# Получить количество удаленный записей в plpgsql

Tags: postgresql

нужен пример - если ничего не удалил - делай то-то (то есть например в переменную сохранить)

В `plsgsql`. Я читал про `DELETE count`, но не понял как его использовать. Мне надо что то вроде

```
   IF m_count=0 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'No objects';
   END IF;
```

чтоб в `m_count` было количество удаленных строк после `DELETE FROM some_tble WHERE some_field=xxxx;`

Comment: Что значит пример? На sql? или на чём? delete возвращает ответ `DELETE count`. Если count = 0 -- значит записей для удаления не нашла...

Comment: В plsgsql. Я читал про этот DELETE count, но не понял как его использовать. Мне надо что то вроде

   IF m_count=0 THEN
  RAISE EXCEPTION 'No routes';
   END IF;

чтоб в m_count было количество удаленных строк после DELETE FROM some_tble WHERE some_field=xxxx;

Comment: Не знаю. На stackoverflow [Variable containing the number of rows affected by previous DELETE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115917/variable-containing-the-number-of-rows-affected-by-previous-delete-in-a-functi) советуют GET DIAGNOSTICS (разд. 39.5.5 документации -- 39.5.5. Obtaining the Result Status )

Comment: да, сработало, спасибо!